# How to measure expected price growth rate for oil?

Tags: price, oil

How can someone measure the expected annual price growth rate for oil?

Also, where can I find past annual price growth rate for oil values?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a futures market for crude oil: for example http://www.cmegroup.com/trading/energy/crude-oil/light-sweet-crude.html gives a price now for May 2018 of US$\$49.54$ compared with a cash price now of US$\$47.82$

The futures price being higher than the cash price is described as *contango* and is why there are excess stockpiles of crude oil.  In the past the comparison has sometimes been reversed, described as *backwardation* and associated with low stockpiles.  For a graph of this over time, see http://marketrealist.com/2017/02/return-backwardation-mean-crude-oil-prices/ though the relationship is more complicated than described there

For historical oil prices the Federal Reserve Bank of St. Louis has several sets of numbers, such as https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/WTISPLC going back to 1946